# How to let COUNT show zeros in tables with many to many relationship?

Tags: sql, left-join

the following query does not show the Groups where no users belong to.
I would like to have the shown with a count of 0 too. How do I do this?

Like this should it be
Group A     8
Group B     0
Group C     2

This is it now
Group A     8
Group C     2

```
SELECT      UsersToGroups.GroupID, 
            groups.Group, 
            COUNT(UsersToGroups.UserID) AS countUsersPerGroup

FROM        users_Groups AS groups

LEFT JOIN   AssociationUsersToGroups AS UsersToGroups ON
            UsersToGroups.GroupID = 
            groups.ID

LEFT JOIN   users_Users AS users ON
            UsersToGroups.UserID = 
            users.ID                                    

GROUP BY    GroupID, 
            groups.Group                        

ORDER BY    groups.Group ASC
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Your group by contains the column of `UsersToGroups`, change it to`GROUP BY groups.ID, groups.Group` will solve your problem

Comment: I tried to change GROUP BY GroupID, groups.Group to GROUP BY groups.ID, groups.Group but then an error is thrown because GroupID is missing in group by.

Answer (score 1):

Query will select all groups

```
SELECT      groups.ID, 
            groups.Group, 

FROM        users_Groups AS groups
```

If you add `LEFT JOIN AssociationUsersToGroups` you should receive groups with number of participants:

```
SELECT      groups.ID, 
            groups.Group, 
            COUNT(UsersToGroups.UserID) AS countUsersPerGroup

FROM        users_Groups AS groups

LEFT JOIN   AssociationUsersToGroups AS UsersToGroups ON
            UsersToGroups.GroupID = 
            groups.ID
GROUP BY groups.ID, groups.Group
```

Comment: I guess I will need the users table to include a where clause to filter some users out.

Comment: @Thorsten . . . That is not part of your question and this answers your question.  For your filtering, you can add a `left join` to users and put the conditions in the `on` clause rather than the `where` clause.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I guess you are right. I will try to find out how to put the conditions in the on clause. Thanks

Comment: I moved the condition to the JOIN, but it does not filter the result out.
LEFT JOIN   users_Users AS users ON
            UsersToGroups.UserID = 
            users.ID
AND users.IsTestData <> 'False'

I am scratching my head.

Comment: Probably, you are counting `UsersToGroups.UserID`. To filter some users out you should count `users.ID` instead of `UsersToGroups.UserID`

Comment: I changed 'Count(UsersToGroups.UserID)' to 'Count(users.ID)' but it gives the same number.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i don't see why you need to join the user table?
There's no need to assuming that you have a foreign key relationship between "users" and "users-to-group" association
table with `ON DELETE CASCADE`

This works for me:

```
-- setting up test-tables and test-data
create table #Groups
(
    ID int,
    GroupName varchar(100)
)

create table #UsersToGroup
(
    GroupID int,
    UserID int
)

insert into #Groups 
values  (1,'Group A'),(2,'Group B'),(3,'Group C')

insert into #UsersToGroup
values  (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(3,1),(3,2)

-- the query you want:
select  g.ID as GroupID, 
        g.GroupName, 
        count(utg.UserID) as countUsersPerGroup
from    #Groups g
        left join #UsersToGroup utg on g.ID = utg.GroupID
group by g.ID, g.GroupName                   
order by g.GroupName asc

-- cleanup
drop table #Groups
drop table #UsersToGroup
```

output:

[image: output:]

Comment: I guess I will need the users table to include a where clause to filter some users out.

Comment: ok but if you do that with a LEFT JOIN on Users table and a WHERE clause it will act like an INNER JOIN. You have to do your filters in the join. E.g. `LEFT JOIN Users u ON utg.UserID = u.id AND u.UserName IN ('John','Harris')`